# Brother MFC 7340 printer/scanner won't scan to email because it can't launch Outlook 2013

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, printer

I launch it, and it doesn't default to use Outlook and requires me to give the path. I do the path to the program files/ms/office/outlook.exe Try again and it gives this **error: Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. The command line argument is not valid. Verify the switch you are using.**

Fixes I've tried:

1. CC updater thing from Brother
2. Uninstall completely and reinstall
3. Install and restart with and withOUT ccupdater

What else can I do? I used the exact same install files (copy->paste) on another computer with 2007 and it worked fine. Nothing unusual about Outlook installed on either computer other than that the one that doesn't work is 2013.

Comment: What Outlook 2013 edition do you have? x64 (64-bit) or x86 (32-bit)?

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question: did you verify that Outlook is selected as the default email client in Windows?

Typically the Brother drivers are programmed with the correct command line arguments for Outlook and other common email clients.  The problem could be that the driver predates Outlook 2013 or that if you have to specify the email client, the Brother driver may be using generic command line arguments.

Check the Brother web site to see if there is a newer driver.  If the driver is compatible with Outlook 2013 and 2013 is set as the default email client, you may have to get fancy with some manual workarounds to make it work.  You might even find it simpler to do something like use a web mail client as the Brother target.